# Do verses 32:5 and 22:47 contradict 70:4?

Tags: quran, tafseer, arabic, contradiction

There are multiple interpretations of يوم, one is that it means "world" in 70:4, and is recorded in Ibn Kathir's tafsir. But my main problem is the meaning of "you count" (تعدّون). A more correct translation following grammar rules of Arabic is that it means "you cause to be counted", but I want to know what it means in the context of the rest of 32:5 and 22:47 in Arabic

> 32:5
> يُدَبِّرُ ٱلْأَمْرَ مِنَ ٱلسَّمَآءِ إِلَى ٱلْأَرْضِ ثُمَّ يَعْرُجُ إِلَيْهِ فِى يَوْمٍۢ كَانَ مِقْدَارُهُۥٓ أَلْفَ سَنَةٍۢ مِّمَّا تَعُدُّونَ ٥ He arranges [each] matter from the heaven to the earth; then it will ascend to Him in a Day, the extent of which is a thousand years of those which you count.
> — Saheeh International

However ٱلأَمْرَ can mean "command" and يَعْرُجُ can mean "[it] will return", and a working meaning can be interpreted with these meanings

> 22:47
> وَيَسْتَعْجِلُونَكَ بِٱلْعَذَابِ وَلَن يُخْلِفَ ٱللَّهُ وَعْدَهُۥ ۚ وَإِنَّ يَوْمًا عِندَ رَبِّكَ كَأَلْفِ سَنَةٍۢ مِّمَّا تَعُدُّونَ ٤٧ And they urge you to hasten the punishment. But Allāh will never fail in His promise. And indeed, a day with your Lord is like a thousand years of those which you count.
> — Saheeh International

> 70:4
> تَعْرُجُ ٱلْمَلَـٰٓئِكَةُ وَٱلرُّوحُ إِلَيْهِ فِى يَوْمٍۢ كَانَ مِقْدَارُهُۥ خَمْسِينَ أَلْفَ سَنَةٍۢ ٤ The angels and the Spirit [i.e., Gabriel] will ascend to Him during a Day the extent of which is fifty thousand years.
> — Saheeh International

There is a narration in Baghawi's tafsir that the day of Judgment is 50,000 years on disbelievers.

So keeping all these in mind what is an interpretation consistent with the narration and verses?

How can days be in fact 1000 years but different for some people. Can this one also be explained? my explanation is that one day is one day for us and is in fact 1000 years, because ALLAH knows everything including that a human day is actually 1000 years, but it's 1 day for humans, and a similar explanation can be made for the 50,000 years one. But does this explanation work?

Answer (score 1):

There are many, many ways of understanding these verses. You could ask about each of these verses alone and you would get full answers of the possible meanings of each of them.

But, since you are asking about how to resolve the contradiction, here are ways to do that:

1. Say it refers to different days. Among the candidates for the days being referred to are: Day of Judgement, one of the of the six days of creation, the time it takes for the angels to go from heaven to earth and back, etc. It is possible for someone to claim each of the verses refers to different days. Perhaps 22:47 doesn't even refer to any specific day and is just an example given to mean Allah is not as hasty as you.
2. Say all of them refer to the Day of Judgement but different people's experience of it. Perhaps one group will feel the Day of Judgement is 50 thousand years long and another group will only feel it is a thousand years long.
3. Say both 32:5 and 70:4 speak about the speed of the angels but about different angels. Some angels go in a day a distance that would take people 50 thousand years to go and some angels go in a day a distance that people only take a thousand years to go.

And there are other ways. Allah knows best.

Comment: Is it in fact 1000 years but 50,000 years on disbelievers? can you explain further with this interpretation. I reached such an interpretation through Baghawi's tafsir on 70:4

Comment: @Vbscript Time is perception. So, the same thing could feel 50,000 years to one group and 1000 years to another group in terms of their life in the dunya.